# How to remove localcheck pointed RDDs from storage

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[image]

I have ever running spark contexts. In my code using localcheckpoint to truncate lineage based on my alogorithm after checkpointed i want to remove RDDs reference please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clean checkpoints you need this conf:

```yaml
spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints    true    #Default: false; Controls whether to clean checkpoint files if the reference is out of scope.
```

See [spark configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html);

If you want to [uncache\remove the RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#removing-data):

```scala
rdd.unpersist()
```